# How to get all products from one order to the list

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have written a query that returns data, here is my code

```
SELECT o.Id, p.ProductName, po.Quantity, p.Price, DeliveryMethod, 
OrderDate, TotalSum, u.UserName FROM [Order] o
JOIN ProductsOrders po ON o.Id = po.OrderId
JOIN Product p ON po.ProductId = p.Id
JOIN Users u ON o.UserId = u.Id
ORDER BY o.Id
```

And it returns next:

```
OrderId ProductName Quantity Price DeliveryMethod OrderDate TotalSum UserName
98         Bed3       1      3000    Express    2018-08-04  7015    Ivan
98         Bed4       1      4000    Express    2018-08-04  7015    Ivan
100        Bed2       1      2000               2018-08-05  2000    Ivan
101        Bed2       1      2000               2018-08-05  5000    Ivan
101        Bed3       1      3000               2018-08-05  5000    Ivan
102        Bed0       1        0    Standard    2018-09-04  1005    Ivan
```

We can notice that for each product - one record

But I want to group all products by one order and get something like that:

```
- orderId
- deliveryMethod
- userName
  - product1   quantity    price
  - ...
  - productN   quantity    price
- totalAmount

101
Courier
John Doe
  Black bag       1   1500
  Fat Bike        1   5000
  Thermos bottle  5   200
Total amount      7500
```

How can I modify the query?

Comment: What you are wanting to do looks like a job for SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS), Microsoft Excel, or another utility. Any attempt to display the results from your query in this format would be like using a toothbrush to paint a wall.

Comment: Does this database have an ORM (i.e. Django)? If you had data models that correspond to the tables, then you could do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this, IMO, would be to select 2 datasets.  First dataset containing the parent Order data, and the second containing the individual ProductsOrders (product line items) for the Orders in the first dataset.

```
-- Select Orders
SELECT
     [o].[Id] AS [OrderId]
    ,[o].[DeliveryMethod]
    ,[o].[OrderDate]
    ,[u].[UserName]
FROM [Order] [o]
    INNER JOIN [Users] [u] ON [o].[UserId] = [u].[Id]
WHERE
    [o].[Id] IN(SomeRangeOfOrderIds) -- (Or however you'd like to filter the results)


-- Select Products (product line items)
SELECT
     [p].[ProductName]
    ,[po].[Quantity]
    ,[p].[Price]
FROM [ProductsOrders] [po]
    INNER JOIN [Product] [p] ON [po].[ProductId] = [p].[Id]
WHERE
    [po].[OrderId] IN(SameRangeOfOrderIdsAsTheQueryAbove)
```

...then take those results and display them however you'd like.  Will this be appearing in a report?  Or on a web page?

Answer (score 0):

I have just implemented this issue in LINQ. Should have noticed that there is many-to-many relationship

```
var orders = db.Orders.Select(o => new
        {
            o.Id,
            o.DeliveryMethod,
            o.OrderDate,
            o.UserId,
            o.TotalSum,
            Products = o.ProductsOrders.Select(p => new { p.Product.ProductName, p.Quantity, p.Product.Price}).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```